# NotFoundHttpException() after Laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel

After installation I change only this:

```
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

        'local' => array('Gandiexn-Laptop'),
    ));
```

Still Laravel throw NotFoundHttpException(). Where is problem? This is default Laravel page because I couldn't start write.

Comment: Please use the search first: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=laravel+NotFoundHttpException%28%29 - Then tell us which of those didn't work for you and why. This is important to make clear how your question is different from the exisiting ones. This is especially important with support requests (e.g. how to configure my routes with my server).

Comment: Have you configured routes properly.

Comment: Have you created the configuration file for your `local` environment?

Comment: I only install Laravel and change up lines.

Comment: Where did you make above change? Did you create a .env file?

Comment: try read this..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166020/laravel-notfoundhttpexception