# Laravel NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a problem with this one route.

```
Route::get('va/{$uniqueid}','AdminController@VaShow')->name('va');
```

and in controller:

```
  public function VaShow($uniqueid = '123'){
      dd($uniqueid);
    }
```

but i still get NotFoundHttpException when trying to visit route. (it have admin prefix but anyway i'm trying to access it directly with url and in view but still same)
in view:

```
{{route('va',['uniqueid'=>$v->uniqueid])}}
```

and I checked in route:list, its there:

```
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/va/{$uniqueid}     | va                 | App\Http\Controllers\AdminControl
ler@VaShow               | web,admin    |
```

No idea what I did wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dollar sign in your route is throwing it off. The variables in the route do not need a dollar sign:

```
Route::get('va/{uniqueid}','AdminController@VaShow')->name('va');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Remove $ symbol.

```
Route::get('va/{uniqueid}','AdminController@VaShow')->name('va');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need the dollar sign. You could add ? at the end of the parameter in case the parameter is optional to send.

```
Route::get('va/{uniqueid?}','AdminController@VaShow')->name('va');
```